# How to Correctly Use .gitignore to Exclude the node_modules Directory?

Tags: node.js, git, version-control, gitignore

I'm attempting to configure my `.gitignore` file to exclude the `node_modules` directory from my Git repository, but I'm uncertain about the correct syntax to achieve this. I've come across three different options and am unsure which, if any, is the correct approach:

1. `/node_modules`
2. `.node_modules`
3. `.node_modules/`

Could someone clarify which of these options correctly excludes the `node_modules` directory, or is there another way to achieve this in `.gitignore`? I'm looking for a method to ensure that `node_modules` is not tracked by Git to avoid unnecessary files in my repository.

I appreciate any guidance or insights you can provide on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use node_modules or /node_modules both should work also try to look at the [node.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore), it will give you an idea on what to ignore in your project

Answer (score 1):

the `node_modules` directory isn't hidden. You should just be able to do `node_modules`

Comment: So, I just have to write "node_modules" on gitignore file and that's it?